# Hiding API key when committing changes to GitHub

Tags: java, html, api

I have a Java project which contains an `index.html` file. In this html file, I need to access an API key with this line of code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABCDEFGHijklmnopqrst12345&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I want to commit this file to GitHub, but I do not want to show my API key. However, I cannot achieve this by storing my API key in an `.env` file since my project has nothing to do with `node.js`, it's just a Java project.

Please give me some advice on how I can store my API key within my project and make sure it won't be committed to GitHub. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java can read from files or environment variables just as well. Or do you mean it's a Java**Script** project? Those are _very_ different things.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using that key in an HTML tag, hiding it from Git commit won't make your key safe from public access because anyways on production the key will be publicly accessible since the clients can see HTML code that the server is sending.

If you just want to make sure that the key won't be committed to Git, then I can think of two methods in that case.

1. Keep the key in a separate file (like the .env that we usually use with nodejs), read the file contents using Java (Since you said Java is used instead of nodejs), and while rendering the webpage simply put that key in the output.
2. Create a javascript file and keep your key in that script file (assign it to a variable)
   And then in your HTML file you can simply write a JavaScript code like this:

```html
<script src="env.js"></script>

<script>
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+myKey+"&callback=initMap";
    $("head").append(s);
</script>
```

Make sure that you're creating a variable with the name "myKey" in your env.js file.

Now you can simply add your env.js file to .gitignore